# IBM Queue Manager over writing the value of User Identifier in MQMD

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

We are trying to write a message to IBM MQ using JMS, we are able to write the message but notice that the field UserIdentifier in MQMD is getting over-written by the QManager.

We've tried both these properties to set user id,

```
message.setStringProperty(JmsConstants.JMS_IBM_MQMD_USERIDENTIFIER, "ourUserID");
message.setStringProperty("JMSXUserID", "ourUserID");
```

We also have these properties before setting the User id,

```
message.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_WRITE_ENABLED,true);
message.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_MESSAGE_CONTEXT,WMQConstants.WMQ_MDCTX_SET_ALL_CONTEXT);
```

also the Queue Manager and Queue have the required configuration,

```
+setall +setid +passall
```

but still we are unable to get required result. What can we do different over here ?

Answer (score 2):

This is an extract from one of my programs:

```
MQQueue d = (MQQueue)destination;
String altusr="myuserid";
d.setMQMDWriteEnabled(true);
outMsg.setBooleanProperty(MQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_WRITE_ENABLED, true);
outMsg.setStringProperty(CommonConstants.JMS_IBM_MQMD_USERIDENTIFIER, altusr);
d.setIntProperty(MQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_MESSAGE_CONTEXT, MQConstants.WMQ_MDCTX_SET_IDENTITY_CONTEXT);
```

It's possible that this only works if you are using the JMSContext API model rather than the older createSession() approach as that can also affect when the underlying MQOPEN or MQPUT1 happens. Which in turn affects whether the context-setting flags are referred to.

Comment: Hey Mark, thanks for your message, is it possible for you to share the code repo for the same ? or any documentation reference ?

Comment: My code is not in a public repo so can't be shared beyond that fragment. Docs are at https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=amffmcja-reading-writing-message-descriptor-from-mq-classes-jms-application

Comment: Hi @Mark, I tried your code but issue still persists. Could you mention the library you used for the same ?